# while loop incrementing range in django

Tags: python, django, gspread

I am using gspread library to read cell values from Google spreadsheets.
I want to loop over the range like:

```
col_index=3
i=0
while i<4:
    cell_values_list=[worksheet.cell(r, c).value for r in range(10,20) for c in range(col_index,col_index+3)]
    ...
    ...
    col_index=col_index+3
    i=i+1
```

instead of using row column values, i want to use

```
worksheetworksheet.range('C10:E20')
```

and in the next iteration i want

```
worksheetworksheet.range('F10:H20')
```

and so on.

can anyone please help me how can i iterate or say increment my column value

Comment: how many columns are there in your spreadsheets? A to Z or more?

Comment: i want to access from column A to N and row 10 to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_addr_int(row, col)` function which will output a string label for your cell, see the docs here: https://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#gspread.Worksheet.get_addr_int

If I get our code right in your case it will be something like:

```
col_index=1
i=0
while i<4:
    start_cell = worksheetworksheet.get_addr_int(10, col_index)
    end_cell = worksheetworksheet.get_addr_int(20, col_index+2)
    cell_values_list=worksheetworksheet.range('%s:%s' % (start_cell, end_cell))
    ...
    ...
    col_index=col_index+3
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in xrange(65, 78, 3): # character ord form A to N
    range_str = "%s10:%s10"%(chr(i), chr(i+2))
    worksheetworksheet.range(range_str)
```